# TypeScript and Webpack. Loading file that don't have typescript definition

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I was trying to use TypeScript with WebPack. Ts-Loader was working fine till I use [Materializecss](http://materializecss.com/). It is not having TypeScript binding. Which I felt ok as there are very few JavaScript things and I can use it for UI purpose by doing type casting with `any`. Code works but Web-Pack is not adding Materializecss JavaScript files in compiled file. As, I am not importing it in TypeScript file.

I can't import it as it is not having definition file for TypeScript.

So, currently I have to fallback to Gulp + Bower approach. It is ok for now but I am missing npm approach that is better for bigger applications IMHO.

Let me know if any further details are required.